# Question about ASP.NET Core with ReactJS template in Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm currently developing a project that use `ASP.NET Core with React.JS` template, in which inside the project there is a standard .NET App, Controller and context for WeatherForecast example and the ClientApp directory for the ReactJS application.

However I am confused about is that how can I use the controller in the .NET Core component to transfer data to the ReactJS application? I have also add a project that use `.NET Core Web API` template to handle the data flow, but that leaves me not knowing how to use the controller and models in `ASP.NET Core with React.JS` since basically I can just use axios to handle fetch requests.

What I am thinking about is to develop a controller for user login and register for the UI with JWT for authentication and authorization, but the data should be passed from the .NET controller to the ReactJS component. Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

Comment: [Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: If you open the project in an editor and take a glance on files like `FetchData.js`, you can easily see how an HTTP request is made via `fetch` to ASP.NET Core Web API and the returned JSON is utilized to update UI elements. If your confusion is about how that request of a URL lands on ASP.NET Core controller class, that's covered by MVC pattern and ASP.NET Core routing rules. Find good tutorials/books and they can guide you through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send http request from "reactjs client" to "net core controller", then get response with the data.
In the template, the weatherforecast controller has an [httpget] api endpoint to return json format data.

Go to Properties/launchsettings.json find the back-end net core hosting port : 7049.
[image]

Then in the browser you could directly visit `https://localhost:7049/weatherforecast` to see the endponit returned json data
[image]

You can see that the front reactjs client port is different(4445).But visit `https://localhost:44445/weatherforecast` you will receive the same json result. That is because there's a proxy rewrite it to the back-end port 7049.

Thus, now you could check the reactjs clientapp/src/components/fetchdata.js. In the bottom, it has a method populate weatherdata. fetch the url `weatherforecast` which actually calls `https://localhost:44445/weatherforecast` then rewrite to `https://localhost:7049/weatherforecast` endpoint. So it could fetch the json data.
[image]